# Mount FAT32: Can't find a valid FAT filesystem

Tags: mount, filesystem, fat32, ntfs-3g

Xubuntu 14.04. `nfts-3g` is installed.

`/dev/sdc` is the Flash drive. I have created new partition with `fdisk` (tried with `cfdisk` too). Tried with `W95 FAT32` code and `W95 FAT32 (LBA)` code. ("b" and "c" in `fdisk`).

After writing the changes I try to mount it with:

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /media/flash4gb/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

dmesg says:

```
[60591.890070] FAT-fs (sdc1): invalid media value (0x73)
[60591.890077] FAT-fs (sdc1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
```

NOTE: Usually the other software like: USB bootable USB creators working well. After they touch the drive, everything is fine. I am not sure FAT32, but the NTFS is well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After creating the partition with fdisk you must create the FAT file system:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdc1
```

Then you should be able to mount /dev/sdc1 with -t vfat.